# History of Mendeleev periodic table of elements as a data visualization

Tags: data-visualization, references, history

I am looking for a comprehensive and authoritative reference (journal article or book) dealing with the history of [Mendeleev periodic table of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) as a data visualization. I am especially interested how  the graphical representation of the table of elements changed over time.

As of now I found Wikipedia article [History of the periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_periodic_table) to be comprehensive (but it is not that authoritative).

I want to use it as (see-also)-type citation (I don't want to use any particular claims), so even a popular science article should be fine.

Comment: There are several [references and links listed on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_periodic_table#References). Are none of those what you are looking for?

Comment: @MånsT I went through it, within things I can access. Unless Google Books blocks the best pages, I didn't find anything focusing on evolution of this data vis (sure, there are some pieces of data vis scattered over many publications). As I am looking for "see-also" reference, I would like to refrain from original research on this topic (I am neither a chemist nor a historian).

Comment: Eric R. Scerri, The Periodic Table: Its Story and Its Significance *may* have the desired information, but I don't have access to it so I cannot judge.

Comment: An image of *the very first graphic* (a manuscript draft in, I believe, Mendeleev's own hand) is online at http://images-of-elements.com/l/draft.jpg.  For subsequent (and preliminary) developments, see [the presentation by David Hobart of LANL](http://periodic.lanl.gov/mendeleev.shtml). The table had acquired its standard (modern) appearance by 1938.  Some innovative visualizations appear on slides 46-48.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original best guesses came up short (at least for the articles I had quick access to). Friendly's [*The Golden Age of Statistical Graphics*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/08-sts268) mentions a derivative of the periodic table is Moseley's discovery of the concept of an atomic number - but doesn't mention the table itself. I quickly checked the work of Michael Friendly and Howard Wainer to see if they had any general pieces on the work - but I found none (quickly).

I don't have quick access to Tufte's book(s) - but he is pretty comprehensive in historical review. It is possible he mentions the periodic table in brief (but I think is unlikely to have a review of the table over time like you envision).

Some perusing on Google Scholar though brought up a *Journal of Chemical Education* that has a few articles of interest. See:

- Diffusion cartograms for the display of periodic table data [(Winter, 2011)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed1000203)
- From Periodic Properties to a Periodic Table Arrangement [(Besalú, 2013)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed3004534)
- Periodic Table of the Elements in the Perspective of Artificial Neural Networks [(Lemes and Dal Pino, 2011)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed100779v)

From there I got lucky and found *[Periodicity, visualization, and design](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10698-012-9154-0)* by Francis T. Marchese - which appears to fit your bill perfectly for a historical narrative (although doesn't cite the other more recent articles I mention).

Comment: I was partly familiar with some musings about the periodic table in cartogram form via John Cook - see [here](https://plus.google.com/107357401349156916755/posts/Xgqo691yHn3) for an older version - although note Harlan Harris's comment about the likely inaccuracy. Here is another variant via John Cook from an article in [*Time* magazine](https://plus.google.com/107357401349156916755/posts/Rs1diTQhMfy).

Comment: +1 for [Francis T. Marchese, Periodicity, visualization, and design](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10698-012-9154-0) - exactly what I need!
AFAIR in Tufte's books periodic table is mentioned asone of the hallmarks of data visualization, but certainly not going into its history (I've skimmed 3 books by him).